# Webapp is running on local tomcat7 but not on linux tomcat7

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, deployment, tomcat7

I have developed a webapp with jsf2 and primefaces 3.2.
The webapp is running local without any problems on a clean tomcat7 installation. So I dropped the .war file in /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps on my Linux server.
The webapp appeared at the tomcat manager but was not running. If i try to start it, the following error shows up.

```
"FAIL - Application at context path /LnB-Sports could not be started"
"FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([after_stop]) for component [org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext@130cd4a] in state [FAILED]"
```

Here is the **catalina.out**

```
Jun 10, 2013 9:45:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/LnB-Sports]
Jun 10, 2013 9:45:58 AM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase destroy
WARNING: Calling stop() on failed component [{0}] to trigger clean-up did not complete.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([after_stop]) for component [org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext@b1666d] in state [FAILED]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:408)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:272)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1043)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1272)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1450)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1547)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Jun 10, 2013 9:45:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
WARNING: Error while removing context [/LnB-Sports]
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext cannot be cast to org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.destroy(ContextConfig.java:1074)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:365)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1043)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1272)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1450)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1547)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Jun 10, 2013 9:53:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2948 ms
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:53:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3164 ms
Jun 10, 2013 9:58:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:58:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:58:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jun 10, 2013 9:58:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:58:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:58:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:58:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2986 ms
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:06 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [3,329] milliseconds.
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/LnB-Sports.war
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:06 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'context/Manager'.
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:06 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'context'.
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext@60659b]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to process either the global, per-host or context-specific context.xml file therefore the [/LnB-Sports] Context cannot be started.
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext.startInternal(FailedContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Jun 10, 2013 9:59:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/LnB-Sports.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext@60659b]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Jun 10, 2013 9:59:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:07 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:07 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2013 9:59:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6362 ms
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Few checks if you remove this war file from tomcat deployment directory, does the tomcat starts correctly? Share the jar files you are using in the war file (/WEB-INF/lib)? Also share any other configurations made externally to tomcat, if so?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your quick reply. When I remove the war, tomcat starts correctly. The jars im using are also present in the /WEB-INF/lib folder. Last but not least I didn't make any externally configurations to tomcat. :(

Comment: I think am a wrongly understood here, I am asking for the list of jars you have in the lib directory.

Comment: ahh okay, here it is:

(WEB-INF/lib)
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.1.jar
javax.faces-2.1.17.jar
jstl.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
primefaces-3.2.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext cannot be cast to org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
```

This suggests that the runtime classpath is for some reason polluted with multiple different versioned Tomcat-internal libraries, such as `catalina.jar`. Those multiple different versioned libraries are conflicting with each other.

You need to make absolutely sure that your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` does **not** contain any servletcontainer-specific JAR file, such as `catalina.jar`, `servlet-api.jar`, etc.. It would make your webapp to be compatible only with the specific servletcontainer make/version where the JAR is originally coming from and totally unportable to another servletcontainer makes/versions. You also need to make absolutely sure that you don't touch Tomcat's own `/lib` folder nor JRE/JDK's own `/lib` or `/lib/ext` which also paricpiates in the runtime classpath (unless you really really know what you're doing, but not understanding this `ClassCastException` indicates that this is not yet the case).

Comment: I think you were right, that the classpath was polluted. I don't know were my misstake was, but I made a new project and copied the sources into it. Now it's running fine. Thanks for your help :)